# What case was Justice Breyer referring to in the argument for Trevino v Thaler

Tags: us-supreme-court, case-law

[Trevino v. Thaler, Oral arguments](http://www.supremecourt.gov/oral_arguments/argument_transcripts/11-10189.pdf)

> **MR. OLDHAM**: Well, Your Honor, I think you
>   could do one of two things. You could always certify
>   the question with the Court of Criminal Appeals if you
>   thought that the question -- that the answer turns on
>   what the Texas procedures are and that the parties
>   disagree with them.
>
> **JUSTICE BREYER**: I tried that once in a case
>   involving Pennsylvania, and the result was such that I
>   resolved never to do it again.
>
> (Laughter.)
>
> **JUSTICE BREYER**: But -- but don't say never.
>   All right. So one thing we got --
>
> **JUSTICE ALITO**: That was a case in which --
>   that was the case in which the Court unwisely reversed a
>   certain Third Circuit decision.

What case were Justices Breyer and Alito referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [blog post](http://joshblackman.com/blog/2014/04/04/that-time-justice-breyer-certified-a-question-to-the-pennsylvania-supreme-court-and-then-reversed-circuit-judge-alito/) tracked this to *Fiore v. White*, a 1999 case in which Breyer [wrote an opinion](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=4157023366955709575&q=fiore+v+white&hl=en&as_sdt=40000003) certifying a question to the Pennsylvania Supreme Court, after which SCOTUS [reversed the Third Circuit](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=12396895581251745262&q=fiore+v+white&hl=en&as_sdt=40000003) *per curiam*. The Third Circuit opinion in question was written by [Circuit Judge Samuel Alito](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=8126056775761412557&q=fiore+v+white&hl=en&as_sdt=40000003).

Comment: So, I went and read the opinions, and one thing I'm still missing is why Justice Breyer decided, in retrospect, it was such a bad idea; it looks like it went rather smoothly. I can think of why *I* think it was a bad idea (letting a state decide whether its own procedure was constitutional), but why did Justice Breyer?